# What is the best way to update Java version on Mac computer?

Tags: java, auto-update

Should I run brew or update Java via the Web or some other method?

Comment: This is not install but upgrade.

Comment: @Joe ... but the answer is the same.

Comment: first update the cask from terminal with help of brew (assuming brew is setup in Mac), following code will be used to update the java

     brew tap caskroom/versions
     brew cask install java8 OR brew cask install java10

Comment: Depends on which distribution you use.  Some come as a package, others as a disk image and others as a zip file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### The Answer

You can update Java by downloading the newer version from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) directly When you install the installer would delete the older version for you.

---

### The OLD Answer (no longer works)

Or you Mac has built in system that would fetch and update java from Oracle for you for you. Go to System Preference > Java > Update > Update Now. It would also be a good idea to turn on "Check for Updates Automatically" that way when a newer version of Java comes out your Mac would ask you to install it and it becomes a simple one click install.

[image]

Comment: Is this still accurate?  On my mac with MacOS Mojave, there is no Java Preferences pane anymore, although I seem to have a java installed at /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

Comment: @Marvin Yes it's not accurate anymore,
They removed Java Control Panel in Java 11.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53176853/1263512

Comment: In 2022 (JRE 19), the direct link for downloading is https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-mac, extract, install and you're done.

Answer (score 7):

Just go to the java page and download the latest version. Upon starting the installation process, the installer automatically detects your current java version, either deletes it and does a complete reinstall or just updates your version.

Comment: the java page is a mess...

Comment: And the required signup to download